# How to fix Problem to use Lxml in python?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, lxml, data-science

I am trying to develop a web scraping application using python. But when I'm going to structure or content on the dataframe (in the case of Pandas), the following error appears:

"ImportError: lxml not found, please install it"

Through PyCharm, I can't add Lxml to Project Interpreter. And in the Command Promp when trying to install it by "pip install lxml" it appears:

"Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\xxx\site-packages (4.5.0)"

I use Windows 10. Do you know what could be happening? thanks!

[código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKVvB.png)

[imports in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbFGE.png)

[error ifor add lxml in pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBooi.png)

[console (cmd)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENN9z.png)

[Pycharm - Settings - Project Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL6pa.png)

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment? _Through PyCharm, I can't add Lxml to Project Interpreter._ What do you mean?

Comment: Hello, `lxml` needs to be installed for the interpreter you are using in Pycharm. For instance, if you are using a virtualenv environment, in Settings > Project interpreter, lxml needs to be listed in the list of packages.

Comment: @AMC Thank you, AMC. It's referring to trying to install package lxml in Pycharm 
as the photo  attached (Pycharm - Settings - Project Interpreter)

Comment: @RaphaeleAdjerad and do you know what i have to do for install Lxml in a Virtual environment????

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded de Project Interpterer, updated a pip then a installation of lxml by pycharm was a success. Thank you all!